# Upload problem on custom made Arduino Mega2560 rebuild

Tags: arduino, timeout

I designed my own PCB to control a couple of motors,
to monitor positions by means of light barriers, as well as via UART with to chat with a barcode scanner and a GSM module.

Since I first made a breakout board for my Arduino Mega2560
have and everything has already worked wonderfully here, I have it on my specially designed board this 1 to 1 recreated according to the documentation from Arduino itself.

I flashed the ATMega16U2 controller with the HEX file so that the
the data is translated from USB to UART.

I also have a programmer with an Arduino Nano built, with the template from the Arduino IDE (see screenshot * .png.) With this I burned the bootloader on my ATMega2560.

This procedure was in a number of forums. I also performed a loop-back test before I burned the bootloader, it worked and I did
have the data sent via the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE
get back.

After the successful bootloader burn, this no longer worked, and I get a timeout when uploading the sketch because the
handshake does not work, although the board from the IDE is correctly recognized. -> avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage (): timeout

I have checked the circuit several times and can therefore use one
exclude circuit errors (Rx & Tx are correct.)

I'm sure I'll find someone here to help me with my problem can help, this problem itself, or a similar one already once and found a solution to it.

Comment: Sorry Screenshot is missing.

Comment: Are you sure it was the correct bootloader? You can scope the RX and TX lines to see if the data is getting to the ATMega2560 and if the ATMega2560 is replying.